# sumar voto al dar clic en foto y no en radio

Tags: php, html, mysql

ya tengo la forma de agregar un voto y lo hace desde un **input type="radio"** pero yo quiero ingresarlo dando clic en la foto desde un **input type="image"**  este código me funciona pero debo necesariamente dar clic en el circulo de radio y luego en la foto para q lo envie ....  insisto no recuerdo como hacer directamente desde la imagen en otras palabras q al dar clic a la foto se envié un voto a favor del aspirante escogido en la foto

```
<form action="modelo/insertar_voto.php" method="post" name="formulario">

    <h1> Formulario de Votación Escolar </h1>

    <?php
        $consulta = "SELECT * FROM aspirante";
            $result = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta); 

            while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                $id_asp = $row["id_asp"];
                $nombre = $row["nombre"];
                $foto= $row["foto"]; 
            ?>
        <div>   
                 <p class="centrado"> <label><?php echo $nombre; ?></label> </p> 
        <p class="centrado">
            <label>
                <img src="public/img/<?php echo $row['foto'];?>">
                <input type="radio" class="radio" id="radio" name="opciones" value="<?php echo $id_asp;?>">
            </label>
        </p>
        </div>

        <?php 
         } 
    ?>
```

Comment: no entiendo que me queres decir... solo arregle tu publicacion que se veia mal...

Answer (score 1):

**Actualización:** Solo crea un enlace para ir a la página donde se va a agregar el voto y envía `id_asp` en la URL:

```
<form action="modelo/insertar_voto.php" method="post" name="formulario">

    <h1> Formulario de Votación Escolar </h1>

    <?php
        $consulta = "SELECT * FROM aspirante";
            $result = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta); 

            while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                $id_asp = $row["id_asp"];
                $nombre = $row["nombre"];
                $foto= $row["foto"]; 
            ?>
        <div>   
                <p class="centrado">
                    <label><?php echo $nombre; ?></label><br>
                    <a href="modelo/insertar_voto.php?id_asp=<?php echo $id_asp;?>"><img src="public/img/<?php echo $row['foto'];?>"></a>
                </p>

        </div>

        <?php 
         } 
    ?>
</form>
```

Después, en `insertar_voto.php` obtienes id con asignación ternaria, para evitar errores: `$id_asp = (isset($_GET['id_asp'])) ? $_GET['id_asp'] : 0;` Luego verificas que sea un id correcto y armas la consulta para agregar el voto.

Comment: ¿Copiaste y pegaste sin analizar el código?, yo no incluí la etiqueta del formulario, espero que no la hayas quitado.

Comment: @MICO, por favor edita tu pregunta para que pongas el código actualizado.

Comment: @MICO, actualicé la respuesta, por favor revisa.

Comment: amigo de antemano muchas gracias ya logre mirar y ordenar el nuevo código con la función y los estilos que me pasaste. Pero la verdad NO me funciona como yo quiero, lo q en verdad necesito es q funciones solamente con la imagen osea que al pulsar la imagen se pueda enviar el voto que no haya q presionar la imagen y el botón, sino q se envié el voto solo con presionar la imagen del aspirante..  no importa si queda asi ocultando el radio o no,  lo q no quiero es q haya mas botón eso en realidad es lo q quiero que al presionar la imagen se vaya el voto sin botón extra la imagen hace eso

Comment: @MICO, entonces lo que quieres es simplemente un enlace, ¡nada que ver con formularios, radios y botones!

Comment: mira voy a plantear mejor la pregunta tengo un formulario q  me trae 3 fotos d la BD quiero con un clic sobre la foto escogida q me pueda enviar un voto para ese aspirante   <?php  $consulta = "SELECT * FROM aspirante";
        $result = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta); 
        while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            $id_asp = $row["id_asp"];
           $foto= $row["foto"]; 
        ?>
    <div>
      <input type="image" name="opciones" value="<?php echo $id_asp;?>" src="public/img/<?php echo $row['foto'];?>" >  
        </div>
    <?php 
     } 
?>

Comment: creia q solo con esta parte dentro del  div me podía salir                                                            <div>                   <input type="image" name="opciones" value="<?php echo $id_asp;?>" src="public/img/<?php echo $row['foto'];?>" >                                                       </div>   porq me muestra las imagenes pero no me suma el voto en la tabla resultado de la BD

Comment: Revisa la actualización.

Comment: ya revise y le las actualizaciones q me sugieres  <a href="modelo/insertar_voto.php?id_asp=<?php echo $id_asp;?>"><img src="public/img/<?php echo $row['foto'];?>"></a> y nada sigue sin pasar el form...                 los estoy haciendo asi y le gregue un boton enviar pero no es lo q quiero <img src="public/img/<?php echo $row['foto'];?>" name="foto">
                <input type="radio" class="radio" id="radio" name="opciones" value="<?php echo $id_asp;?>">

Comment: amigo muchas gracias ya lo logre gracias a tu ayuda ya funcioan solo con dar clic a la imagen...